# Heroku Django Migrate Not Working

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am in my way learning python with django, and when I tried to sync with Heroku, there's an error showing I haven't migrated them yet. I am pretty sure have done it, but the console still saying so.

Iam sure I left an obvious part. But still can't find which one.

[This image reflected exactly what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJeGg.jpg)

Comment: Try to run migrate command for each app that you created.

Comment: Check your database connection in settings and test your apps seperately

Comment: In this project, I have only this single app. I am not sure it's the problem @AdilMalik

Comment: I opened my settings.py and seems the whole thing is in their default.
I even be able to runserver and view my app. Just dont have a clue why not applied migration.

Perhaps this line saying DATABASE ?
`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}`

Edit: Only a little with have been changed. Like Installed apps, middleware, and templates.

Comment: yes but if you see your image, APPLY ALL MIGRATIONS doesn't include your app. So just do this --> heroku run python manage.py migrate your_app_name @muflichkamil

Comment: I wish I can. Forgot to state that I have tried that method too. Please have alook at these.
https://snag.gy/a0womQ.jpg

Comment: Try to do one more thing. Its looks the same but i think may be you should run 'python manage.py makemigrations your_app' . May be it works. @muflichkamil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use sqlite on Heroku. You must use the postgres add-on.

Sqlite stores its db on the filesystem, but on Heroku the filesystem is ephemeral and not shared between dynos. Running a command spins up a whole new dyno, with its own database file which is migrated, but then thrown away.  The next command - or the web dyno itself - won't see that db.

Comment: You don't have to use postgresql. Heroku supports many database choices that are compatible with Django.

Comment: I have no idea to do so. I was just following the tutorial and he haven't changed anything in that sqlite part.

Comment: But his runs pretty well

Comment: Sorry, who is "his"? I will say it a third time: you **cannot** use sqlite on Heroku. That is the source of the problem. Change it to a proper database using one of the add-ons, and you will be fine.